# PHP Call from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to call my PHP file from Database whenever a new row inserting into table..For that i like to go with TRIGGER concept...To call a PHP file we need a UDF sys_exec()..Could anyone explain me the procedure of installing this UDF in my DB...I am using macintosh,PHPStorm...

Also i am going to place this PHP file in my webserver..In sys_exec() method format is like this...

```
   sys_exec('C:/php/php.exe C:/path/to/script.php');
```

Can i use this same procedure for calling a PHP file which is placed in webserver???Because PHP.exe file will not be there...If not possbile how could i call the PHP file whenever new row getting inserted into table..

Comment: check this once http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.in/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is not good decision. In our projects with php and mysql we use triggers and all other actions which should to react on new records, we hang to shedule with checking. It is simple and reliable chain of different systems and easily to search bugs.

Comment: Hm, I will try.. 
The final decision depends on the project requirements. If you need the immediately reaction on event in db with calling external code, I advice You look to PostreSQL or others servers which support call of code.. I never use or try sys_exec, it looks like crutch.. Mysql is good to store data and search in stored when You need data. Who need to know when data is inserted? May be subject to which it is necessary to know, be able to make a request to the database checking for new lines?

Comment: I want to send notification to my user when new row inserting into DB...For that purpose only i chose sysexec

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if your code to update the db istelf sends the notification?

Comment: I wrote a pair systems with notifications.. In my system one component "writer" just creates row "event" and other component "sender" is running by shedule each minute. It queries "events" with empty field "sended" (NULL). Sheduled code provide processing every "not sended" "event" - defines receivers, sends and marks processed events as "sended". Field "sended" has datetime type - and we see when event was sended. I know what code is running on each site of the system. I can stop "writer" and "sended" separately. Excuse my English.

Comment: Correct Solo. Using the 'Schedule' is the same as using 'at' command. I just prefer 'at' cos it started with Unix before Windows even came around.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, but calling sys_exec (or any other system commands) it probably the worst way to do it. Just go by Solo.dmitry's answer, or look into using the 'AT' command on the server to run the php file or a regular basis which returns new rows.

Comment: AT is a command on windows or unix/linux that runs from the command line. it will allow you run any command at a time period you specify when you 'create' the at command. You can specify every second, which would be silly, onece a day, etc. google 'linux at command' or 'windows at command' to see how it works. you could use it to update a file with links to new rows that have been inserted, which in turn you could auto-reload in your browser on a regular basis to view the file. Again, this is just one way....